# Visual Studio 2012 and missing files

Tags: svn, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Got a weird issue with Visual Studio 2012 Professional edition.

Three of us at work are using this, and we're working on the same project, MVC4/EF5/.Net4.5/C# and Oracle.

We're using SVN for version control.

What's happening is that when my colleague commits a new file to a project, when I update my working copy, the file comes through, but it's not showing in Visual Studio as being a part of the project, it's only there if you choose Show All Files and then manually add it to the project.

Now I know what you might be thinking, we're not committing the CSPROJ files or something like that, but I've double checked and we definitely are; the only thing we're ignoring are .user/.resharper and .suo files.

Anyone else come across this problem ?

Comment: By the way, the kicker is - it's intermittent :S

Comment: If you add a file and did not do a Build or Save All (not save), the project file will not be saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the exact same setup with our git.

That sounds like he's not saving his .csproj before doing a commit. Visual studio is pretty bad about saving the .csproj at the same time it saves a new file to the disk, so sometimes you have hit save all to force a save of the .csproj file. I've gotten in the habit of doing that every time I interact with git.

You should verify by doing a side by side comparison of his .csproj file and yours when seeing this behavior. They are simple .xml files under the hood. Open it with notepad, and look though the various `<Compile Include="fileName.cs" />` nodes. When he's added a file and you do not have it, you should see that you are missing the appropriate `<Compile />` while he has it.

A side by side comparison tool such as beyond compare can make this very easy.

Comment: Looking at the commmit logs, I think this is very likely; I'll check next week to be sure, but yes - I'm sure this is what's actually happening. Good call!