# Files show as hidden in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, hidden-files

Hei,

So we have a whole group of people working on the same project and every now and then some files show as hidden, you know the blank file icon like obj or bin.

[image]

See my font and texture? They should be normal.

So, I can see them in the folder but not in solution explorer without hitting the Show Hidden Files. I can also modify them but I would like them back.

I have been trying to see if there was a solution but all I get is blogs on how to show hidden files.

So I found this thread 
[Visual Studio 2012 and missing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101818/visual-studio-2012-and-missing-files) 
that seems to be giving the reason of my problem. People are not saving properly before pushing to github.

Now is there a solution to this?(apart from saving properly) Can I make all of those files become normal files?

Cheers

Comment: right click on file, include in project (or something like that)

Comment: You should put that as an answer since it is fixing my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply right click the files/folders and include them to source control again.

This usually happens if people check in new files/folders but do NOT check in the updated project file, too. The project file contains a list of all files which should be included within the solution. If this runs out of sync, exactly this crap will happen... ;)

Simply instruct your folks to properly check-in. Or do code review on check-in and verify that the project/solution file(s) are also checked in.

Comment: Since you show as first you get the answer. But yep it seems to be what I needed. Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 3):

They show up as hidden because they're not part of the project/solution, but they are on your file system.

You can right-click the files and click *Include in Project*

If this does not solve the issue after checking in.  The project file is what is not properly getting checked in.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that they are not pushing the project file (file with extension .csproj). It holds all references to files included on the project so it needs to be pushed when new files are added.

Let everyone know that they need to push this file in order to everyone to catch latest changes on project.